# I would like to find a line in a file and replacing a string

Tags: text-processing, sed

I would like to find a certain line in a file containing a String "AUTOINSTALL_VTK" and replace in this line the String "OFF" with "ON" using a bash script.

It should be possible to do the replacement with sed but how do I tell sed to only replace "OFF" with "ON" in this one line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
sed -i '/AUTOINSTALL_VTK/ s/\<OFF\>/ON/' file
```

I added word boundaries `\<` and `\>` to prevent replacing `OFF` within some other word, e.g. `OFFICIAL`.

---

To run multiple commands for the matching line, you can use `{ ... }`.
Example to switch `ON` and `OFF`:

```
sed -i '/AUTOINSTALL_VTK/{s/\<OFF\>/ON/n;t;s/\<ON\>/OFF/;}' file
```